# Automatic realm join during kickstart

Tags: active-directory, sssd

I need help in automation of joining CentOS hosts to working samba AD server. I've used winbind succesfully with the following command in a script

```
net ads join -U Administrator%Passwordhere
```

but now I switched over to SSSD because its easier, quicker and more robust way. Unfortunately I cannot manage to automate the command

```
realm join
```

because I can't pass the pw as argument in a command or script. Also the command seems to fail during kickstart because of the generic hostname (localhost.localdomain). So I've tried putting in script, executed via rc.local. Unfortunately that works only sometimes. For some reason sometimes it takes like 2-3 reboots for the script to have effect on the machine.

I'd appreciate some advices

Answer (score 1):

kickstart has a realm command, see [the syntax reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax#sect-kickstart-commands). [Fedora QA's test case makes a good example.](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Testcase_realmd_join_kickstart) And the RHEL knowledgebase has [another example of joining to AD during kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3213301).

Create a computer user. I think you can do this in a %post script too.

```
adcli preset-computer --one-time-password=MyPassword --domain=dc.example.com anaconda1
```

Partial kickstart that ensures host name and required packages installed.

```
network --hostname=anaconda1.example.com
realm join --one-time-password=MyPassword dc.example.com

%packages
@base
@core
# Packages for realm commands
krb5-workstation
realmd
adcli 
krb5-libs 
samba-common  
oddjob-mkhomedir 
oddjob 
sssd 
samba-common-tools
pam_krb5
```